# C++ CTRL+C Handler having undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, winapi, crash, undefined-behavior

I have a large C++ program running on Windows 10, that has a main system answering socket requests and 2 threads running monitoring systems via separate instances of a socket client class.

At software shutdown (CTRL+C or exit X button), I need to be able to gracefully stop 2 threads, the threads shut down some physical equipment via sockets.

When a CTRL+C event is registered, the `sExit()` function is called.
This function sets an atomic variable `kill_child_threads=true` to kill while loops in the remote threads. Unfortunately, when I join the remote threads, they do not seem to join, or at least the join does not block the `sExit()` function.

Then the `sExit()` function randomly 'exits?', without completing all the code. But the program seems to cleanly shutdown according to windows and exit codes. VS2019 does not detect any issues, and the program exits with 0xc000013a (Windows CTRL+C).

When I try to debug step into the `sExit()` function, it will run a few lines, but at some point it 'crashes' or just exits the entire program without any exceptions or completion of the function. It does not happen at the same line every time, rather at different points. It sometimes 'crashes' before or after the thread.join()'s are called, and based on logging, the program crashes often before the completion of the 2 child threads.

The configuration below historically worked with 1 thread, but upon adding a 2nd thread recently, I get what I would consider undefined behavior.

Any help or methods to debug would be very helpful.
Please note the LOG system is thread safe.

Def in top of main.cpp & Creation of threads inside `main(void)`:

```
//top of main.cpp
std::thread *rotor_thread;
std::thread *heat_thread;

//main()
rotor_thread= new std::thread(TubeControl::rotorThing);
heat_thread= new std::thread(HeatExControl::heatThing);
```

```
BOOL WINAPI sExit(DWORD CtrlType)
{

    if ((CtrlType == CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT) | (CtrlType == CTRL_C_EVENT)) {
        LOG(DEBUG) << "Entering Close Event or Ctrl-C Event";

        //Kill Tube rotor thread & spin to ECO mode.
        kill_child_threads.store(true, std::memory_order_seq_cst);
        try 
        {
            heat_thread->join();
            rotor_thread->join();
        }
        catch (std::exception & e)
        {
            LOG(ERROR) << "Issue Killing:" << e.what();
        }
    //More stuff here on main thread...
    //That never executes, or sometimes partially executes.
}
```

Thread 1:

```
void rotorThing(void)
{
    while (!kill_child_threads.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst))
    {
        //Do Thread safe stuff.
        //Sleep
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    }
    //Program shutting down
    try
    {
        LOG(INFO) << "[Rotor] xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.";
        //Do Thread safe stuff.
    }
    catch (std::exception & e)
    {
        LOG(ERROR) << "Issue shutting down tube" << e.what();

    }
}
```

Thread 2:

```
void heatThing(void)
{
    enum HEAT_STATE { COLD, HOT };
    HEAT_STATE heat_state = HEAT_STATE::COLD;
    LOG(DEBUG) << "[Heat] Starting Heat Exchanger Monitoring Thread.";
    std::string resp = "";

    while (!kill_child_threads.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst))
    {
        //Check tube speed, and Hx temps and flows
        hwHxSock->sendCmd("hx,get_inlet_temp");
        float itemp = stof(hwHxSock->getRespString());
        LOG(DEBUG) << "[Heat Xfer Mon] xxxxxxxxx";
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));
    }

    hwHxSock->sendCmd("hx,get_inlet_temp");
    float itemp = stof(hwHxSock->getRespString());
}
```

Comment: Unrelated: Since the program is exiting, you probably don't care if the threads are leaked, but... Pointers to threads are seldom necessary. You should be able to `std::thread rotor_thread;` to define the thread and then `rotor_thread = std::thread(TubeControl::rotorThing);` to start the thread in `main`.

Comment: Can you confirm the way you are triggering the call to sExit , like actually keying in control-C , has not also triggered some process shutdown activity?

Comment: What makes you think it's crashing?

Comment: I attempted to add better detail of what really happens. @WilliamClements - I am doing ctrl+c and x button, both have same effect.

Comment: @user4581301  - You are probably correct I do not need pointers, I do not delete anything, since the program is shutting down.

Comment: @JonathanPotter - The `sExit` function does not finish all of the code, and even stepping through it in visual studio, it will suddenly exit before reaching the end of the function, and not always at the same point.

Comment: @RbMm - The threads both end up simultaneously performing tasks then the entire program exits. The shut down for each thread is ~10 seconds due to a few socket commands to remote systems. So it is easy to physically see that they are not being executed in the .join() order, and are happening at the same time. Both child threads also do not typically complete all the tasks during shutdown, telling me something is forcibly closing them.

Comment: I also feel the urge to stress, this did function fine until a 2nd monitoring thread was added. The threads are completely separate independent classes, so I do not believe there is any interaction issues, unless the windows socket library somehow has issues with multiple threads accessing it?

Comment: the *conhost.exe* call `TerminateProcess` for your process. not in case ctrl+c, but in case close - you can not wait too long. your process will be external terminated

Comment: so all what you write here unrelated - system force internal call `TerminateProcess(, STATUS_CONTROL_C_EXIT)` for your process

Comment: @RbMm - I'm not sure I understand what your saying?

Comment: i say that `TerminateProcess(, STATUS_CONTROL_C_EXIT)` called for your process in case `CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT` after usual 5 seconds. what is unclear here ?

Comment: and this is only in case `CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT`, but **not** in case `CTRL_C_EVENT`

Comment: Would that cause the joins to act weird as well? I'll have to try making the routines faster to test your theory.

Comment: @MadHatter - look like you not understand. any *joins* here unrelated at all. all your code unrelated at all. your process **terminated** by system

Comment: and what i say - not theory but 100% fact

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when user click close on console window - [HandlerRoutine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/handlerroutine) callback ( `sExit` in your case) receive `CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT`. with this event - system force terminate your process after [`SPI_GETHUNGAPPTIMEOUT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-systemparametersinfoa) (by default 5000ms). whatever you do in your process(*Circumstances - any*) - after some timeout - if you not exit yourself - your process will be external terminated with `STATUS_CONTROL_C_EXIT` code. this exactly give effect "exit in a random place" (really your code can be at any place when terminate called)

but in case `CTRL_C, CTRL_BREAK` - **no timeout** - look for [*Timeouts*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/handlerroutine) section in the end

Comment: Short of "SPI_SETHUNGAPPTIMEOUT" in the windows API, is there another way to tell windows I'm not "Hung"? Thank you for the help.

Comment: @MadHatter how i know - no for console application. if you use GUI subsystem - you can ignore or handle in any way `WM_CLOSE` message (for any self window). but in case console window - you have only several seconds (by default - 5) before you process will be force terminated. and no option ignore `CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT`